# Compiler error with simple defun using cond

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying some basic stuff out in CL and don't understand why this won't compile:

```
(defun ifelse (the-test)
  (cond ((the-test) (format t "passed test"))
    (t (format t "failed test"))))
```

Compiler says:

```
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: THE-TEST
```

I have done similar with `if` without trouble:

```
(defun test-if (the-test)
  (if the-test
      (format t "passed")
      (format t "failed")))
```

The compiler doesn't complain. Wouldn't a `cond` work the same way, as they are both testing a condition?

```
; in: DEFUN IFELSE
;     (DEFUN IFELSE (THE-TEST)
;       (COND ((THE-TEST) (FORMAT T "passed test, true!"))
;             (T (FORMAT T "failed test, boo hoo"))))
; --> PROGN EVAL-WHEN 
; ==>
;   (SB-IMPL::%DEFUN 'IFELSE
;                    (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA IFELSE
;                        (THE-TEST)
;                      (BLOCK IFELSE (COND (# #) (T #))))
;                    NIL 'NIL (SB-C:SOURCE-LOCATION))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable THE-TEST is defined but never used.

;     (THE-TEST)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: THE-TEST
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     THE-TEST
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions
```

Comment: Which implementation of Common Lisp are you using?  What else are you defining/compiling involving `the-test`?  Your code compiles and works without warnings or other problems in SBCL.

Comment: You may want to have the same source code in the error message and in the question. Currently it is different.
Why does COND does not the same way as IF? Because they are different constructs. Check the documentation for their syntax.

Comment: @RainerJoswig valid point regarding the source; i got lost in all the parenthesis. However it does look like the conditional test for my `cond` and the `if` do in fact behave the same way here, once the issue wass sorted out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the full compiler error

```
(DEFUN IFELSE (THE-TEST)
 (COND ((THE-TEST) ...
```

Your code is different:

```
(defun ifelse (the-test)
  (cond (the-test ...
```

You probably changed your code during your tests.

In your actual code you use the variable **the-test**

In the compiler error the function tried to call  the function **(the-test)**